# How to determine which Makefile is targeting a given file?

Tags: c++, makefile

I am modifying a shared library. I copied the contents of a directory to a new sibling directory and ran a Make on the entire library. However, I am receiving the following error:

`Make: *** No rule to make target /opt/orchestra/tests/ToolsNew/Makefile’, needed by ‘Makefile’. Stop.`

Why would a copy of a directory which could be made just fine not be Make-able?

Comment: Could it be that the copy lost the case? If you `ls -l /opt/orchestra/tests/ToolsNew`, maybe us see `makefile` instead? I guess you use a linux VM, but maybe Windows was involved in copying Tools to ToolsNew?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got a bit confused , you are looking for a answer to  ::

How to determine which Makefile is targeting a given file?
or 
Why would a copy of a directory which could be made just fine not be Make-able?

first Q : it seems to be the new copy of the make but if you are still in doubt ....

check where you fired the command .... the path , if a filename is not specified then by default make looks for a 
  descriptor in the current directory -- which is where the command was run...

OR

if there are two or more similar looking makefile in the same dir , you are not sure which one was used 
eg : makefile and Makefile then you could check the .MAKEFILE_LIST  -- it contains the names of each of the makefile that is parsed by the make in  general , so there you get the name and the order in which they would have been looked up.

the way to check that ::
         make -p < /dev/null | tee MAKE_P.TXT

( caution : -p option would list every setting for make .... the file will be a but lengthy)

this should  help you find the descriptor makefile being used .

Second Q:

from ur edit it seems that the real issue is :  can't Pastebin the Makefile because it is located on a VM which I don't have access to right now. – RouteMapper 16 hours ago

I would check in the code ...... call could be like ......

```
 cd $(proj_dir) &&  $(MAKE) ;
```

if you use the older  $(proj_dir) value here ie /opt/orchestra/tests/Tools , even if u cant copy the older Makefile you can use it , during run it will use the current enviornment setting that you have...... i think it should work !!

hope this helps !!
Let me know if you need some thing else ?

Answer (score -1):

The reason is to be found in the output. Note how it's complaining about the file `/opt/orchestra/tests/ToolsNew/Makefile`? Basically the warning is telling you that the file is missing, and you have no Make rules defined to generate a new copy.

You should verify that that file exists, I'm willing to bet it doesn't.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe a permissions issue? What is the full path of the original directory, and the full path of the new, copied directory? Could you Pastebin the Makefile itself?

Comment: Old directory: /opt/orchestra/tests/Tools. New directory: /opt/orchestra/tests/ToolsNew

Comment: I can't Pastebin the Makefile because it is located on a VM which I don't have access to right now.